# Connect to mysql docker on tutum endpoint

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm using Tutum to host my application via docker. The first container needed is offical mysql container. I already got it up & running. After that, Tutum provide a service endpointfor me to connect to it:

[image]

However, I don't know how to connect to it via the provided endpoint (especially using Sequel Pro). Could anyone help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in "[tutum support: Your first service](https://support.tutum.co/support/solutions/articles/5000525024-your-first-service)", then endpoint is the url with port exposed by the image.
You would use it as an external client accessing to that url.

Note that you [can set a port to be publish statically instead of dynamically](https://support.tutum.co/support/solutions/articles/5000050090-deploying-a-web-service) (`-p x:y` instead of `-P`, in `docker run` lingo)

[image: http://cdn.freshdesk.com/data/helpdesk/attachments/production/5001309687/original/Screen_Shot_2014-09-29_at_8.19.20_PM.png?1412114073]

But in case of your containerized application, you don't need that endpoint.
Your container, if **[linked](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/)** to the mysql container, you will be able to use mysql services from your app container directly.

See "[Service discovery and links](https://support.tutum.co/support/solutions/articles/5000050090-deploying-a-web-service)"

[image: https://s.tutum.co/support/images/service-links-diagram.png]

You don't have to use the full endpoint url from your app container.

Note that tutum:

> provide a simple way to connect any container on any stack to any other container on your account without having to create service links.
>
> A container can always discover other containers on the same stack using the container name as hostname.